# SQL use GROUP BY such that it results in the original SELECT

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have a SQL query that is something like

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM budget GROUP BY {{PLACEHOLDER}}
```

where {{PLACEHOLDER}} will be replaced in the code. Is it possible to replace it by something that will result in the same output as the following statement?

```
SELECT price FROM budget
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: Why not just remove the SUM()?

Comment: Actually there are times when this is a neat approach - I've seen it used quite regularly when constructing dynamic queries in Access.

Comment: is it for some SQL injection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a unique column, like an autogenerated id you can use that

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM budget GROUP BY budget_id
```

will be equal to

```
SELECT price FROM budget
```

**if every row has a different budget_id** (identity, autoincrement fields will fit the bill)

Now, I urge you to reconsider the wisdom of doing such a hack, why don't you put an if where it matters?

Comment: ROW_ID() on SQL Server? Not in any version I've worked on, If you mean ROW_NUMBER(), you won't be able to aggregate on it without a CTE or derived table. However, you are correct about grouping on the key column

Answer (score 1):

```
...GROUP BY NEWID()
```

Random per row, so never aggregates. And separate to key column(s), schema etc

Comment: What if you are unlucky (and get the same id twice)? Or is that guaranteed to return differently for each row on a single query? It's also RDMB specific

Comment: It's a GUID: the chances of collision are astronomical.

Comment: Great. Still RDBMS specific I meant up there.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to include GROUP BY directly in your placeholder if and only if a placeholder exists:

```
if (!empty($placeholder)) {
    $placeholder = 'GROUP BY ' . $placeholder;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you wish to omit the group by effective.
In that case, make it GROUP BY ROW_ID
This will yield the same results

Comment: You are assuming the poster uses SQL Server, no such guarantee in the question (so far.)

Comment: Well, it's still assuming a rdbms version. My mistake though. (And Tzury's)

Comment: tagged as SQL. That usually related to RDBMS ASAIK

Comment: Yes, but not to SQL Server (or whatever engine supports ROW_ID) or you meant a unique id?

Comment: that was just a name for the field holding the primary_key/row_id/unique_id whatever you prefer to call it.